# System.Threading.Timers VS Windows Service VS Schedule Tasks

Tags: .net

For a task that should be done every hour, which one do you recommend and why?
since system is running real time applications with high load of CPU and memory and I/O, I want best approach with minimum overhead of checking if it is time to do task or not!

Edit: It's possible that the task takes more than one hour to perform it's job so it shouldn't triggered twice.

Edit: I have an application which is doing mass of image processing and I/O on disk and network. the task can be included both in this application or as an external application.

Comment: Seems like you answered it yourself, Scheduled task will be your friend

Comment: Depends. Really. Not quite that simple.

Comment: If I have a choice, I always go for the console app type, together with a Scheduled Task entry. Much easier to debug (and often to deploy) compared to a service.

Comment: Agreed - a separate service makes little sense. Adding a scheduler to a more compelx application often does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. In general - is the task something which is part of the realtime application? Then a scheduled task triggering the processing or a system.threading.timer may be relevant. Windows service makes no sense AS YOU ALREADY HAVE ONE.

Example:

- Financial trading applciation that regularly does consolidations of open positions every hour. The trading application IS a windows service. I can jsut use a timer to make sure a method in it is called once every hour passses.

Or is it an external task? Like a routine clearning up logfiles.

- Scheduled task. A windows service has overhead 59 minutes of the 60 every hour, so to say, as it blocks memory.

Comment: A windows service IS an application, but an application IS NOT a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Depends by what "every hour" means. If every hour is an exact time (4PM, 5PM) I would look at a scheduled task. Keep in mind that a scheduled task will be governed by the priority rules on the server. Meaning, if the server has to do a task with a higher priority your scheduled task may not fire exactly when you want it to. The only issue that comes to mind is that this may be a disconnected process from your current process (another separate application running).

From my experience Thread.Sleep() is much more reliable than Timers. It's not impossible to get a Thread to stop and start at an exact time it just takes a little more work.

In my situation we had a windows service where the Thread would sleep for X minutes then check the database to find out if it was time to do something. It was a very stable way for running a task throughout the day. We used a scheduled task in the beginning for simplicity but ran into the service priority issue a couple of times. Which is why we ultimately went to the Thread.Sleep() approach.

If the task is a long running task and could span the entire hour you are looking at a multi-threaded service which gives you a single point of failure for multiple tasks. I would start out with a scheduled task until it proves it can't do the job.